# Listening for JavaScript from WKWebView doesn't work Swift 3

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, wkwebview

After researching hours on WKWebView still I don't get how JavaScript injection works.

I set up a WKWebViewConfiguration properly, use a WKUserContentController, I add a WKUserScript to that. Then I add the WKUserContentController as a userContentController for the WKWebViewConfiguration. I then create the WKWebView with the configuration and set the ui, navigation and scrollview delegate. I also add a script message handler to the controller to listen to when the element in the UI is tapped, though that tap never gets called.

I add this WKWebView as a subview in the viewDidLoad, my code looks like this:

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let controller = WKUserContentController()
let scriptSourceCode = "myJavaScriptCode"
let script = WKUserScript(source: scriptSourceCode, injectionTime: WKUserScriptInjectionTime.atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: true)
controller.addUserScript(script)
controller.add(self, name: "MyStuff")

webConfiguration.userContentController = controller

myWebView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: webViewHolderView.frame.width, height: webViewHolderView.frame.height), configuration: webConfiguration)
myWebView.uiDelegate = self
myWebView.navigationDelegate = self
myWebView.scrollView.delegate = self

self.webViewHolderView.addSubview(myWebView)
```

Once I get the data I want to put in my web view I load that into with my custom css that is stored locally.

```
func setupLayoutForWebView(with text: String) {

    var bodyText = text
    let strCssHead = "<head><link rel=\'stylesheet\' type=\'text/css\' href=\'local.css\'></head>"
    bodyText = bodyText.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let strBody = "<body>\(bodyText)</body>"
    if text != "" {
        myWebView.loadHTMLString(String.init(format: "%@%@", strCssHead, strBody), baseURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "local", ofType: "css")!))

    }
    myWebView.bindFrameToSuperviewBounds()
}
```

Then I listen to the script message and I want to evaluate the JavaScript once that message is called but this method was never called.

```
func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    if message.name == "MyStuff" {
        self.myWebView.evaluateJavaScript("functionInMyJavaScript", completionHandler: { (obj, error) in
            print(obj)
            print(error)
        })
    }
}
```

What am I still missing?